# Why is NPM still showing 6.4.1, even though 6.9.2 is installed?

Tags: npm, npm-install

[image]

I have run the various different commands suggested on SO to upgrade `npm` to 6.9.2, and it looks like I was able to make the install successfully.

However, when checking the version directly, it still shows `6.4.1` and continues to show the popup suggesting to make the upgrade when I go to run a **Firebase** command at the command line; in this case `firebase deploy`

Notice in the screen shot:

- for command `npm -v`, it shows 6.4.1
- for command `npm view npm version`, it shows 6.9.2

Not sure what I might be missing here .. how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you run "which npm"? Have you ever used "nvm"?

Comment: In my env., calling `which npm` , returns `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/npm`

Comment: I see the SO posts on `nvm` but was trying to see if I could get it working with what I have.  I get confused with all the *pkg installer* options out there - eg, `brew`, etc; so was trying to minimize invoking different installers .. as I'm never clear on which is the best one to use. I recall I've tried to use `nvm` in the past.  I can give that a go again .. will update my findings here

Comment: Was more wondering if you'd used it before because it could have been throwing your installation off

Comment: Oh - interesting, I was incorrect then when I assumed you were suggesting I try with `nvm`.  I guess the aforementioned attempts at running different installers may be the problem, not the solution

Comment: In searching how to uninstall `nvm`, I'm seeing that it looks like `node` will also be uninstalled.  Is it that I should have `npm` or `nvm` installed for nodejs, but not both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a gist post that finally solves it:
https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689 *(thanks Google)*

First line there explains the source of the issue:

> Installing node through Homebrew can cause problems with npm for globally installed packages.

The post has a lot of discussion about this, so good for all the actual details.. Big credit +50 goes to the poster there.

As suggested by @dbramwell in OP comments, looks like there was a conflict with having multiple installers on the OS.

**Copying** the commands in here for convenience/reference:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

=====

Running some of the commands I was getting error output about permission, but the final step still worked:

```
$ npm -v
6.10.2
```